# Draw a graph in a NSView using values entered by the user

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to draw a graph using Swift. I have created a custom `NSView` and a `NSView` class.
In the `ViewController` I would like to call a method that updates the `NSView` and draws the complete graph using values entered by the user.

```
import Cocoa

class Graph: NSView {

    let startPoint = NSPoint(x: 10, y: 10)

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.whiteColor().set() // set white color
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)      // fill the Rect in the View

        // draw axes lines
        NSColor.blackColor().set()
        NSBezierPath.strokeLineFromPoint(startPoint, toPoint: NSPoint(x: Double(dirtyRect.width) - 10.0, y: 10.0))
        NSBezierPath.strokeLineFromPoint(startPoint, toPoint: NSPoint(x: 10.0, y: Double(dirtyRect.height) - 10.0))
    }

    func drawGraphicsOfNewteork(arrayOfData: [NSTextField]){
        // Here I would draw in the View some lines using the arrayOfData
    }
}
```

Comment: Call it from inside `drawRect`.

Comment: Do all the drawing inside `drawRect`. Call `setNeedsDisplayInRect` if you want to update the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation at all? Searching for "drawing" turns up the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

As others have stated, drawing is done from within `drawRect()`. The system will call it at the "right time", after you flag it by setting `needsDisplay` to true/YES.